# Can't write simple php code to call aws sqs

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, amazon-sqs

I have very little experience with PHP, so please bear with me. I'm attempting to follow the AWS documentation example to confirm that I can connect to AWS SQS using the AWS PHP SDK, but I'm getting stuck...and it's definitely something dumb that I'm doing. Here's my php file (called stuff.php):

```
<?php
header('Content-Type: text/plain; charset=utf-8');
require '/home/ubuntu/vendor/autoload.php';
// Create the queue using the AWS-PHP-SDK function, create_queue, and store it 
// in the '$newqueue' variable.
$newqueue = $sqs->create_queue($queuename);
// Print the created queue results.
echo '<br></br><h2>CREATE QUEUE</h2>';
print '<pre>' . print_r($newqueue, true) . '<pre><br/><br/>';
?>
```

Which is basically copied from the AWS documentation with the require address updated. 
I created an ~/.aws/credentials file using this format:

```
[default]
aws_access_key_id = YOUR_AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID
aws_secret_access_key = YOUR_AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY
```

But when I load the file in my browser, the Apache2 error.log sends me this:

```
[Mon Dec 15 20:46:26.460172 2014] [:error] [pid 2625] [client 10.0.3.1:48211] PHP Notice:  Undefined variable: sqs in /var/www/html/stuff.php on line 7
[Mon Dec 15 20:46:26.460203 2014] [:error] [pid 2625] [client 10.0.3.1:48211] PHP Fatal error:  Call to a member function create_queue() on a non-object in /var/www/html/stuff.php on line 7
```

I assumed that $sqs would have a preset value assigned from the SDK,but perhaps I'm supposed to manually assign something: I have no idea what that might be.
Thanks,

Comment: maybe a create, php says that $sqs is not an object

Comment: it would help to see what the `create_queue()` is

Comment: Unless I'm missing something (which is definitely possible), create_queue() is an SDK command run against my AWS account. I tried giving some value to $queuename - using $queuename = "myname" but it didn't help.

Comment: You're missing some critical steps. The docs are quite clear: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/aws-sdk-php/guide/latest/service-sqs.html

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to the latest version of the [AWS PHP SDK documentation](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/aws-sdk-php/guide/latest/service-sqs.html), you need to create an SqsClient object instance using the provided factory method and then you will be able to create SQS queues, receive/send messages from/to them and so on.

Download the [latest ZIP version of AWS PHP SDK](https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-php/releases), unzip it into your directory project and use the following script in order to create and send a message using SQS Client.
N.B.: remember to put the real relative path to the aws-autoloader file and the right AWS credentials.

```
<?php
require './relative/path/to/aws-autoloader.php';
use Aws\Sqs\SqsClient;
use Aws\Common\Credentials\Credentials;

$credentials = new Credentials('YOUR_ACCESS_KEY', 'YOUR_SECRET_KEY');

// Instantiate the SQS client with your AWS credentials
$client = SqsClient::factory(array(
    'credentials' => $credentials,
    'region'  => '<region name>'
));

$result = $client->createQueue(array('QueueName' => 'my-queue'));
$queueUrl = $result->get('QueueUrl');

echo "SQS queue url: $queueUrl";

$client->sendMessage(array(
    'QueueUrl'    => $queueUrl,
    'MessageBody' => 'Hello World!',
));
```

Comment: That worked perfectly! I was using this guide: http://aws.amazon.com/developers/getting-started/php/  Thanks!